# "Cannot import resource" exception randomly after deploying Symfony2 application

Tags: symfony

After deploying my Symfony application on a server I remove the cache using command:

```
sudo rm -rf app/cache
```

Usually everything works fine but from time to time I got an exception with message:

```
Cannot import resource
"/var/projectsssssss/src/Project/UserPanelBundle/Controller" from 
"/var/projectsssssss/src/Project/UserPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml".
```

Then, I remove cache again and it's working until random next deploy. I use annotation for Routes. Exception is thrown when using Controller `generateUrl` method here is a stack trace:

```
#0 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(75): Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Loader\\FileLoader->import('@UserPanelBundl...', 'annotation', false, '/var/projectsss...')
#1 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php(75): Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Loader\\YamlFileLoader->load('/var/projectsss...', NULL)
#2 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(75): Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Loader\\FileLoader->import('@UserPanelBundl...', NULL, false, '/var/projectsss...')
#3 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php(52): Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Loader\\YamlFileLoader->load('/var/projectsss...', NULL)
#4 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/DelegatingLoader.php(57): Symfony\\Component\\Config\\Loader\\DelegatingLoader->load('/var/projectsss...', NULL)
#5 /var/project/app/cache/main/classes.php(1742): Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Routing\\DelegatingLoader->load('/var/projectsss...', NULL)
#6 /var/project/app/cache/main/classes.php(1451): Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Routing\\Router->getRouteCollection()
#7 /var/project/app/cache/main/classes.php(1400): Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Router->getGenerator()
#8 /var/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php(45): Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Router->generate('userpanel_apps', Array, false)
#9 /var/project/src/Project/UserPanelBundle/Controller/AppsController.php(26): Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\Controller->generateUrl('userpanel_apps', Array)
#10 [internal function]: Project\\UserPanelBundle\\Controller\\AppsController->indexAction()
#11 /var/project/app/bootstrap.php.cache(1426): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /var/project/app/bootstrap.php.cache(1390): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1)
#13 /var/project/app/bootstrap.php.cache(1566): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true)
#14 /var/project/app/bootstrap.php.cache(617): Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true)
#15 /var/project/web/app.php(28): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request))
#16 {main}
```

I suppose there is some problem with cache generation but how to avoid it?

**EDIT**

My `routing.yml`:

```
default:
    resource: "@UserPanelBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: You should remove the cache using : `php app/console cache:clear --env="prod"`. That would be the proper way

Comment: But it does not clear classes cache what I want.

Comment: @keepkimi Looks more to be an issue with the annotations in your Controller, what version are you running? Can you paste your composer file?

Answer (score 0):

You actually deleted the cache folder

sudo rm -rf app/cache

it should be

sudo rm -fr app/cache/*

please try to use the php app/console for such things as its much better. You don't have to even use sudo on it

And another you need to re create the folder and gives

sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs

the www might change depending upon your apache/nginx/other web server username

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted wrong command. Of course, I delete cache using `sudo rm -rf app/cache/*`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found where the problem is. One of controllers class name didn't have `Controller` suffix. @catchamonkey looks like you were right :).